Flutter web - integration test interaction between two applications
Problem
We have 2 flutter applications  (A and B) running on the web on different domains.
Application A redirects to application B and eventually application B redirects back to application A. (this is needed to perform an OAUTH2 flow)
At the moment, we have separate integration tests on each application.
However, this misses some critical paths in the interaction between the two applications.
The main issue is that we are running the integration tests with chromedriver but once application A redirects to application B, seems like chromedriver loses the connection to the application and nothing can be done after.
Desired behavior:
We would like to be able to perform tests on application A, that would somehow be redirected to application B, be able to interact with it and after be redirected back to application A to continue with tests.
Is there a way that this could be achieved, knowing both apps are flutter and build by us?
Edit: Chromedriver Configuration
We start the chromedriver like this:
chromedriver --port=4444

We start the flutter integration tests like this:
flutter drive \
  --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \
  --target="$file" \
  -d web-server \
  --browser-name chrome \
  --driver-port 4444 \
  --web-port 8080 \
  --web-browser-flag "--disable-dev-shm-usage" \
  --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security" 


It would help if you would tell us how you're configuring Chromedriver in this case.

Thanks :) I added the configuration in the original post.
